# Joined tables and databound controls; how would I bind my image controls so they will be bound to different images?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, databound

I didn't know exactly how to phrase this question, so sorry if it sounded a little weird to you guys. It is a follow up to [my question about joined tables and table aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037064/i-have-a-stored-procedure-that-needs-to-pull-info-from-the-same-table-twice-how), only this time my issue is with the ASP.NET markup.

As I said in my previous question, I am making a cheat page for the game [Doodle Creatures](http://joybits.org/games/doodle-creatures/#all). I have a Select statement that joins two image directories - Animals and Genes - in order to display the images as shown below. The script now works, but one of my image bindings is wrong.

Here are the first five combinations as they should be:

- Seagull + Big = Albatross,
- Snake + Big = Anaconda,
- Wasp + Small = Ant,
- Cow + Fast = Antelope, and
- Ant + Small = Aphid

[image: My image bindings are wrong. I laughed a little bit when I realized it. :-) I am so close!! :-D]

Here are the combos as they are now:

- Albatross + Big = Albatross,
- Anaconda + Big = Anaconda,
- Ant + Small = Ant,
- Antelope + Fast = Antelope, and
- Aphid + Small = Aphid.

  ' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [CreatureCombos]
  INNER JOIN [Animals] AS Animal1 
         ON [CreatureCombos].[NewCreatureID] = Animal1.[AnimalId]
      INNER JOIN [Animals] AS Animal2 
         ON [CreatureCombos].[ComboAnimalID] = Animal2 .[AnimalId]
  INNER JOIN [Genes] ON [CreatureCombos].[ComboGeneID] = [Genes].[GeneId];">

  ' Width="25%" />+' Width="25%" />=' Width="25%" />

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue has everything to do with `SELECT *` - your query has the `Animals` table specified twice, and the *select* is returning every field of every table, so you might be getting something like...

- AnimalId (from Animal1)
- AnimalImage (from Animal1)
- AnimalId (from Animal2)
- AnimalImage (from Animal2)
- ComboAnimalId (from CreatureCombos)
- ...

I'm not sure how `Bind("AnimalImage")` ends up selecting which instance of the `AnimalImage` field, but my bet is on the `SELECT *` being the culprit.

Instead of `SELECT *`, specify exactly which fields you need to fetch, and make sure each field name only appears once in your result set:

```
SELECT 
     Animal1.AnimalImage AS AnimalImage1
    ,Animal2.AnimalImage AS AnimalImage2
...
```

Then you can `Bind("AnimalImage1")` when you want the image from the `Animal1` table, and to `AnimalImage2` when you want the image from the `Animal2` table.

Comment: It took me a few tries, but I got it. My SQL ended up looking like this:

'SELECT [Animal1].[AnimalImage] AS AnimalImage1, [Animal2].[AnimalImage] AS AnimalImage2, [Genes].[GeneImg]
FROM [CreatureCombos]
 INNER JOIN [Animals] AS Animal1 
           ON [CreatureCombos].[NewCreatureID] = Animal1.[AnimalId]
      INNER JOIN [Animals] AS Animal2 
           ON [CreatureCombos].[ComboAnimalID] = Animal2 .[AnimalId]
 INNER JOIN [Genes] ON [CreatureCombos].[ComboGeneID] = [Genes].[GeneId];'

Thanks so much for your help! :-D